# Hiding the column separator in multicols

Tags: multicol, rules

By default, the multicol package produce a line between different columns. Is it possible to disable this line?

Comment: `multicol`uses `\columnseprule` for the width of the separator rule, but it is not set by it. So either you have a modified version of the package or something else is setting it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is not the default behaviour here, but as the manual states, the width of the line is decided by the `columnseprule` parameter. `\setlength{\columnseprule}{0pt}` will remove the line.